# Using unquote_splicing in macros with modified lists

Tags: macros, elixir

Elixir's `unquote_splicing` works without issues when directly unquoting passed lists. For example, calling the macro below `Test1.wrap([1,2,3])` will correctly return `[0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0]`.

```ex
defmodule Test1 do
  defmacro wrap(nums) do
    quote do
      [0,0,0, unquote_splicing(nums), 0,0,0]
    end
  end
end
```

---

But if I make any changes to the list and then try calling `unquote_splicing`, Elixir won't even let me define the macro:

```ex
defmodule Test2 do
  defmacro double_wrap(nums) do
    quote do
      doubles = Enum.map(unquote(nums), & &1*2)

      [0,0,0, unquote_splicing(doubles), 0,0,0]
    end
  end
end
```

This will directly raise a compile error:

```ex
warning: variable "doubles" does not exist and is being expanded to "doubles()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  iex:37: Test.double_wrap/1

** (CompileError) iex:37: undefined function doubles/0
    (elixir) src/elixir_locals.erl:108: :elixir_locals."-ensure_no_undefined_local/3-lc$^0/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) src/elixir_locals.erl:108: anonymous fn/3 in :elixir_locals.ensure_no_undefined_local/3
```

---

I have tried a bunch of things so far, such as:

- Using nested quotes
- Using `bind_quoted`
- Going through `Macro` and `Code` docs

but nothing has worked and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is returned by a macro, is directly injected in place of the calling code. [`Kernel.SpecialForms.unquote/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#unquote/1) (as well as `unquote_splicing/1`) is used to get access to the caller context. That is why your code raises: there is no local variable `doubles` defined in the caller context.

What you can do, would be to declare `doubles` outside of the `quote` block.

```rb
defmodule D do
  defmacro double_wrap(nums) do
    doubles = Enum.map(nums, & &1*2)
    quote do
      [0,0,0, unquote_splicing(doubles), 0,0,0]
    end
  end
end

require D
D.double_wrap [1,2,3]
#⇒ [0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0]
```

That said, this is happily resolved:

```rb
doubles = [1,2,3]
quote do: [0,0,0, unquote_splicing(doubles), 0,0,0]
#⇒ [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

And this is not, because there is no `doubles` in the caller context:

```rb
quote do
  doubles = [1,2,3]
  [0,0,0, unquote_splicing(doubles), 0,0,0]
end
#⇒ ☠️  ** (CompileError) iex:7: undefined function doubles/0
```

The error message says *undefined function*, because [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) tries a local variable, and if it does not find it in the current context, it attempts to call the function with this name and the arity zero.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to reach outside the `quote` block to retrieve the value of `doubles` when `doubles` is defined inside the `quote` block.  Variables that are defined inside a quote block automatically have their values embedded in the AST.  Therefore, you can use the function [List.flatten()](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#flatten/1):

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro double_wrap(nums) do
    quote do
      doubles = Enum.map(unquote(nums), & &1*2)

      List.flatten [0,0,0, doubles, 0,0,0]
    end
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> c "a.ex"
[A]

iex(2)> require A
A

iex(3)> A.double_wrap [1, 2, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0]

iex(4)>
```

Comment: That was just an example. What if I wanted to spread the list as arguments of a function `some_fun(:first, unquote_splicing(doubles), :last)` or expand them in a tuple instead of a list? `{0, unquote_splicing(something), 0}`. How will I do it for a value that has been modified or already unquoted?

Comment: Depending on the problem https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/3.11.0/Ecto.Query.API.html#splice/1 could come handy as well